.NET MAUI InvalidateMeasure on ScrollView won't reset height when within a RefreshView on iOS
When records are removed (via pull down refresh) the ScrollView doesn't resize (shrink in height) based on the new content length, which it should provided: (svMain as IView).InvalidateMeasure();
The following works on Android, but not on iOS.
To reproduce:

10 items are preloaded
Click the "Add 10" button
Pull-down from the top to refresh

ReportsPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testrv.ReportsPage"
             Title="ReportsPage">
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RefreshView x:Name="rvMain" Grid.Row="0" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" RefreshColor="{DynamicResource Primary}">
            <ScrollView x:Name="svMain">

                <Grid Margin="20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" x:Name="gridMain_row_0"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="gridMain_row_1"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" x:Name="gridMain_row_2"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" x:Name="vslHeader" Spacing="10"></VerticalStackLayout>

                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" x:Name="vslBody" Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Start">

                        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Add 10"></Button>

                        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="vslFeed" Spacing="10" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Azure"></Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="2" x:Name="vslFooter" Spacing="10"></VerticalStackLayout>

                </Grid>

            </ScrollView>
        </RefreshView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

ReportsPage.xaml.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace testrv;

public partial class ReportsPage : ContentPage
{

    ObservableCollection<string> Labels = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ReportsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(vslFeed, Labels);
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        await SetLabels();

        ICommand refreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
        {
            // IsRefreshing is true
            rvMain.IsRefreshing = true;
            await SetLabels();
            rvMain.IsRefreshing = false;

            (svMain as IView).InvalidateMeasure();
        });
        rvMain.Command = refreshCommand;
    }

    private async Task SetLabels()
    {
        Labels.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            AddLabel();
        }
    }

    private void AddLabel()
    {
        Labels.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam feugiat tincidunt lacinia. " +
            "Fusce at magna et odio finibus consectetur vel vel velit. Integer eu felis vel lorem efficitur semper sed sagittis justo. " +
            "Mauris hendrerit ex semper augue posuere ornare. Vestibulum rhoncus commodo risus, id interdum nibh dictum nec.");
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            AddLabel();
        }
    }
}


Could you please post more code snippets (e.g. the code of view model) so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

The ICommand call is called from OnAppearing(). I did try from a ViewModel too, but that didn't work either so I tried it from the .xaml.cs file instead.

I upgraded from .NET7 to .NET8 and it solved the issue.

Maybe you miss the topic Can I answer my own question? from the help center
